# SonarQube Blocker Issue NullPointerException might be thrown as 'contacts' is nullable here

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a method that returns list of contacts. When I am running this code on SonarQube server. It shows a blocker issue stating **NullPointerException might be thrown as 'contacts' is nullable here.**. How to resolve this?

```
    List<Contact> getContactDetails(){...}

    public void checkSize() {
      List<Contact> contacts = getContactDetails(); 
      syso(contacts.size()); 
    }
```

Comment: Your `getContactDetails()` might return `null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your implementation of `getContactDetails()`, this method might return `null`, and so the line

```
syso(contacts.size());
```

might fail due to an NPE because `contacts` could be `null`.

Fix this by either adding

```
if(contacts != null) {
    syso(contacts.size()); 
} else {
    // exception, error handling or nothing
}
```

or by not returning `null` in `getContactDetails()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar is complaining that you're calling `.size()` on something that might be `null`. So make sure you don't do that:

```
List<Contact> getContactDetails(){...}

public void checkSize() {
  List<Contact> contacts = getContactDetails(); 
  syso(contacts == null ? "contacts is null" : contacts.size()); 
}
```